# Tablelayout losts information when the phone turns (Android)

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a table layout, which waits for an information to arrive. When the data arrives, I fill the table dynamically. But when I turn the phone 90 degree, the table disappears. 
The code:

```
{
TableRow row;
TextView t1, t2;
ArrayList<InfoPair> values;
values = processResults(r);
Iterator it = values.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            InfoPair pairs = (InfoPair) it.next();

            row = new TableRow(c);

            t1 = new TextView(c);
            t2 = new TextView(c);

            // t1.setTextLocale(new Locale("hu", "hu"));

            t1.setText(pairs.getLabel());
            t2.setText(pairs.getValue());

            t1.setWidth(200);
            t2.setWidth(280);

            t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            t2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);

            infoTable.addView(row);

            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

What should I do, if I want the table to hold the information and not to disappear when I turn the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way

```
 <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.app" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

this is the main thing `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`